# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException : com.adobe.xmp.XMPException

Tags: java, metadata

I am using MetaData Extractor to extract some metadata from my Image file , It was working flawlessly  until today morning but today  I encountered an exception

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException : com.adobe.xmp.XMPException
```

and control of my web application redirected to  `error.jsp` as expected

**[Also Found this article to resolve the exception](https://code.google.com/p/metadata-extractor/wiki/Troubleshooting)**

but my code to extract is wrapped up in `try-catch block` So why the exception didn't get catched in catch block

**Entire Stack Trace** :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/adobe/xmp/XMPException
        at com.drew.imaging.jpeg.JpegMetadataReader.extractMetadataFromJpegSegmentReader(JpegMetadataReader.java:112)
        at com.drew.imaging.jpeg.JpegMetadataReader.readMetadata(JpegMetadataReader.java:71)
        at com.drew.imaging.ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(ImageMetadataReader.java:108)
        at com.drew.imaging.ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(ImageMetadataReader.java:95)
        at myPackageName.myClassName.readLocationExifData(myClassName.java:274)
```

**Relevant Code :**

```
try{
    Metadata metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(file); --> Line 274
    GpsDirectory directory = metadata.getDirectory(GpsDirectory.class);
    GpsDescriptor descriptor = new GpsDescriptor(directory);
}
catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
return null;
}
```

Note : This application is in production , So it's not easy to simply add up the jar file and redeploy the application

Comment: Well you are returning a null, are you making provision for that?

Comment: Yes i handling situation when null is being returned  !

Comment: This happened because xmpcore.jar is not in the classpath, a dependency of metadata-extractor.

Answer (score 0):

Please run this program and understand, had it been `Throwable`, would have worked for you.

**Program 1 - catch with `Throwable`**

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            throw new Error();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            System.out.println("hi");

        }
    }
```

**output**

```
hi
```

**Program 2 - catch with `Exception`**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            throw new Error();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("hi");

        }
    }
```

**output**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error
```

**Program 3 - catch with `Error`**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            throw new Error();
        } catch (Error e) {
            System.out.println("hi");

        }
    }
```

**output**

```
hi
```

Comment: **[here is the documentation of readMetaData() method](http://metadata-extractor.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Javadoc/com/drew/imaging/ImageMetadataReader.html#readMetadata%28java.io.File%29)** , Nothing mentioned about weather it will throw any Error or Throwable , also i am facing this problem for 1 specific case in Production environment not for every one , So could not rely on hit and trial basis

Answer (score 0):

You have probably mismatched the version of the `metadata-extractor` JAR and the `xmpcore` JAR. Try upgrading the version of `xmpcore`.

If you are using `metadata-extractor-2.16.0.jar`, `xmpcore-6.1.11.jar` has the class that is missing in your question and should therefore prevent that exception from being thrown.

Comment: I asked this question 6 years back, now I don't even know what was the issue back then, why are you answering questions from way past :)

Comment: I think I must have googled it or something, not sure!